# Codeignighter Start with Field (dbforge)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Is there a way to tell a mysql field to start counting from `n` or 1000

For the below example, I want the IDs to start from 1000 not 1.

```
$tables = array(
    'products' => array(
        'id' => array('type' => 'INT', 'constraint' => '11', 'unsigned' => TRUE, 'auto_increment' => TRUE, 'primary' => TRUE, 'startwith'=>1000),

));
```

Answer (score 0):

In plain Mysql yes you can set auto_increment no as you wish to just define the value in defaults

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `id` INT (11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)  AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000 ;
insert into `products` 
(`title`)
values('test'),
('test1');
```

### [See Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d0664/1)

or if you table is already created you use alter to set auto_increment value

```
ALTER TABLE `products` AUTO_INCREMENT = 2000;
```

### [See Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5ed30/1)